# Removing a pair from a vector of pairs

Tags: c++, vector, stl, erase

I have a vector of pairs

```
std::vector<int,double> lambda;
```

I would like to remove the kth element, i.e

```
lambda.erase(&lambda[k]);
lambda.erase(lambda[k]);
```

Both of these attempts throws a no matching function call error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<std::pair<int, double> >::erase(__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::pair<int, double> >, std::pair<int, double> >::value_type&)’
    lambda.erase(lambda[k]);
```

Comment: `std::vector<int,double>`, typo of `std::vector<std::pair<int, double>>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`std::vector::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) expects iterator as its argument; not the element itself or pointer to element.

You could

```
lambda.erase(lambda.begin() + k);
```

Comment: I did not realise that it was exactly the same as that in the case where we have only one template parameter instead of a pair of template parameters. I was under the (false) impression that & was somehow overloaded and would return an iterator instead of a pointer. Thanks for the answer.